# Xcode Signing Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native project at school under my friend's account. I downloaded it to google drive and opened the Xcode file to run it, (taking care of the signing under my account) but its saying:

"no account for team "******" add a new account in the Account preferences pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials."

I'm also receiving this error:
No signing certificate for "IOS development" found: no signing certificate matching team ID "*****"

the ID it's listing isn't the same as mine..
do I have to somehow use my friend's ID to run this project? I've gone through a whole page of stack overflow questions. Do I need to go to school and download the certificate somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: my friend's Xcode project was signed under his account, using a different certificate than the one I had in my keychain. Heres how you fix that.

1. get on the computer that the project you want to share is on.
2. if you're on a Mac, open keychain Access in the finder
3. find your Xcode certificate. Download it.
4. Share it with yourself via email or whatever you want to use
5. in order to save it into your own keychain on a different computer, open the certificate on the device you are trying to open your project on.
6. Run your Xcode project! It should work!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the Xcode project the team is set. Just change that to a team that you are a member of.

Comment: I already selecting my apple profile in the general area, so I don't know where else the "team" would be. I changed it under general and build settings

Answer (score 0):

I might be running into this issue soon as well with incoming collaborators on my project, give this a try - https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/203647716-Authorize-an-Additional-User-to-your-iOS-Developer-Account - it's inviting users to join your development team, and be sure to check the box that gives you access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

```
Login to App Store Connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/).
Open the Users and Access section.
Click the '+' button in the top-left corner of the page.
Enter the new users details.
Grant the user with at least the Admin or App Manager role.
Enable 'Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'.
```